# installing python's pycraf on AWS linux AMI

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-ec2

How can I get `pycraf` python library (https://bwinkel.github.io/pycraf/install.html#linux) installed on aws linux?

Initially, I used the linux's python3.9 and pip to install from the source by doing `git clone https://github.com/bwinkel/pycraf` , `cd pycraf`, and `python -m pip install .` which fails. AWS linux ami doesn't let me scroll to copy/paste logs.

Next, I'll install older version of python (3.7) with anaconda on the linux AMI to see if that can get it installed. The Windows installation - which works with python 3.9 - shows the following packages.

```
Cython  0.29.33 3.0.2
Jinja2  3.1.2   3.1.2
MarkupSafe  2.1.2   2.1.3
Pillow  9.4.0   10.0.1
PyGeodesy   23.1.9  23.9.21
PyYAML  6.0 6.0.1
affine  2.4.0   2.4.0
astropy 5.2.1   5.3.3
attrs   22.2.0  23.1.0
branca  0.6.0   0.6.0
certifi 2022.12.7   2023.7.22
charset-normalizer  3.0.1   3.2.0
click   8.1.3   8.1.7
click-plugins   1.1.1   1.1.1
cligj   0.7.2   0.7.2
colorama    0.4.6   0.4.6
contourpy   1.0.7   1.1.1
coverage    7.0.5   7.3.1
cycler  0.11.0  0.11.0
exceptiongroup  1.1.0   1.1.3
folium  0.14.0  0.14.0
fonttools   4.38.0  4.42.1
geographiclib   1.52    2.0
geovectorslib   1.4 1.4
h5py    3.8.0   3.9.0
hypothesis  6.64.0  6.87.0
idna    3.4 3.4
iniconfig   2.0.0   2.0.0
kiwisolver  1.4.4   1.4.5
matplotlib  3.6.3   3.8.0
numpy   1.24.1  1.26.0
packaging   23.0    23.1
pandas  1.5.3   2.1.1
pip 21.3.1  23.2.1
plotly  5.12.0  5.17.0
pluggy  1.0.0   1.3.0
psutil  5.9.4   5.9.5
pycraf  2.0.1   2.0.1
pyerfa  2.0.0.1 2.0.0.3
pyparsing   3.0.9   3.1.1
pyproj  3.4.1   3.6.1
pytest  7.2.1   7.4.2
pytest-arraydiff    0.5.0   0.5.0
pytest-astropy  0.10.0  0.11.0
pytest-astropy-header   0.2.2   0.2.2
pytest-cov  4.0.0   4.1.0
pytest-doctestplus  0.12.1  1.0.0
pytest-filter-subpackage    0.1.2   0.1.2
pytest-mock 3.10.0  3.11.1
pytest-openfiles    0.5.0   0.5.0
pytest-remotedata   0.4.0   0.4.1
python-dateutil 2.8.2   2.8.2
pytz    2022.7.1    2023.3.post1
rasterio    1.3.4   1.3.8
requests    2.28.2  2.31.0
scipy   1.9.3   1.11.3
setuptools  60.2.0  68.2.2
six 1.16.0  1.16.0
snuggs  1.4.7   1.4.7
sortedcontainers    2.4.0   2.4.0
tenacity    8.1.0   8.2.3
tomli   2.0.1   2.0.1
urllib3 1.26.14 2.0.5
wheel   0.37.1  0.41.2
```

Used Linux's python3.9 and pip to install from the source, which fails, as follows. 1)`git clone https://github.com/bwinkel/pycraf`, 2) `cd pycraf`, and 3) `python -m pip install .`

Comment: "AWS linux ami doesn't let me scroll to copy/paste logs" this sounds like client behavior.  Are you using `ssh` to connect and if so what terminal program?  "Next, I'll install older version of python (3.7) with anaconda" 3.7 is already end of life.  Don't install it anywhere. Stop guessing random solutions - first you have to *identify the problem*.  If you're stuck because you can't scroll to see the logs, use a better terminal program or learn better how to use the one you are using